# Always get a System.NotSupportedException when quitting a view after subscribing to OnPreDrawListener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-webview, xamarin.forms

I'm in the process of developing an app to display booking information via a client's API in Xamarin.Forms. They wanted a section to display several blocks of information, and that information is often styled with HTML tags (we have no control over how this data is returned). As a quick way to throw a view together to display this information, I created a view which consists of a series of individual webviews to display this information inside a scrollview.

To make this page look less horrendous, I have made a custom renderer for the webview that, when content has been loaded, will resize the view to encapsulate all of the content without scrolling.

Now the actual problem:
To achieve this, inside the custom renderer, in the `OnAttachedToWindow()` callback, get the webview's ViewTreeObserver and call the `AddOnPreDrawListener()` method to make use of the `OnPreDraw()` callback;

The resize is performed in that callback, if the ContentHeight is greater than 0 then it resized the page and returns true.

Then in the `OnDetachedFromWindow()` callback, I check that the VTO is alive, and unsubscribe from the OnPreDraw listener.

Simple, Right?

The page works exactly as expected when navigating to it, however when trying to navigate away, It ALWAYS throws this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type ExtendedWebViewRenderer from native handle 0xbe9f6eac (key_handle 0xf883b13).
```

The error does not occur if I remove all the ViewTreeObserver event subscription stuff, but if I do that, then the page will not resize accordingly.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I have included the brief source code for this. I would appreciate any help on this:

### Source

```
public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer, ViewTreeObserver.IOnPreDrawListener
{
    ExtendedWebView _xwebView = null;
    WebView _webView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        _xwebView = e.NewElement as ExtendedWebView;

        _webView = Control;
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
    {
        base.OnAttachedToWindow();

        // Here assign a ViewTreeObserver to monitor when the view's children need to be resized.
        var _vto = _webView.ViewTreeObserver;
        _vto.AddOnPreDrawListener(this);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        var _vto = _webView.ViewTreeObserver;
        if (_vto.IsAlive)
        {
            _vto.RemoveOnPreDrawListener(this);
        }

        this.Control.ClearCache(true);
        this.Control.ClearAnimation();
        this.Control.StopLoading();

        base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    public bool OnPreDraw()
    {
        if (_webView != null)
        {
            // We get the view's content height and apply that to the parent view.
            int contentHeight = _webView.ContentHeight;
            if (contentHeight != 0 && contentHeight != _xwebView.HeightRequest)
            {
                int desiredHeight = contentHeight + _webView.PaddingBottom + _webView.PaddingTop;
                _xwebView.HeightRequest = desiredHeight;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```